# sys.dm_exec_query_stats returns 'invalid column name'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When I execute this statement in SSMS (SQL Server 2012):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats
```

the statement fails and it returns about 20 messages saying

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dm_exec_query_stats, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Invalid column name 'total_dop'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dm_exec_query_stats, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Invalid column name 'last_dop'.

And so on.
Can anybody explain what's the problem here?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you using a script based on `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` system view ?

Comment: Just added a screenshot.

Comment: @Bogdan: None that I'm aware of, but how could I check whether I'm using a script based on this system view?

Comment: It looks like bug. All this columns are related to 2014-2016. Which version of SSMS do you have?

Comment: I would also check `SELECT @@VERSION` and install latest SP/CU.

Answer (score 3):

Your [`mssqlsystemresource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/resource-database) database is out of sync. Looks like manual replacement of the resource database in `binn` folder, which obviously is not a supported scenario. You must contact MS support to troubleshoot and fix your problem.

Perhaps we can confirm the case, if you run this and post the results:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ResourceVersion');  
GO  
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ResourceLastUpdateDateTime');  
GO
```

Comment: *Looks like manual replacement of the resource database in binn folder, which obviously is not a supported scenario* SMH...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

I installed the latest Service Pack and the problem is gone now.

Thank you all for your cooperation and help.

Bliek